# How to install git-it with no configure file or binaries?

Tags: debian, software-installation

I am trying to install [git-it](https://github.com/jlord/git-it-electron/releases) on a Raspberry pi running GNU/Linux Debian Stretch.

The unzipped folder does not have a configure file, and there is no binary folder. There are no instructions on how to build the package from source in the README file or the website.

```
git-it-electron/
├── assets
├── CONTRIBUTING.md
├── docs.md
├── empty-data.json
├── empty-saved-dir.json
├── lib
├── LICENSE
├── main.js
├── menus
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── resources
└── tests
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The build instructions are in [`CONTRIBUTING.md`](https://github.com/jlord/git-it-electron/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md):

```
git clone https://github.com/jlord/git-it-electron
cd git-it-electron
npm install
npm start
```

You need at least `npm` version 3; follow [the upstream instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) to install that on your Pi.